# Fancybox - ASP.NET OnLoad

Tags: asp.net, webforms, fancybox

I want Fancybox to work without a click, but instead open automatically on load.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

content .cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Presenter.InitializeView(this);

    string myScript = "$('#divMessageBox').fancybox();";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", myScript, true);
}
```

content .aspx

```
<div id="divMessageBox" style="width:400px;height:100px;overflow:auto;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="testando Fancybox" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register it to run when the page loads using [`RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx?ppud=4), like this:

```
string myScript = "$('#myFancybox').fancybox();" //add options if needed
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", script, true);
```

Comment: Ok, but #myFancybox can be a div?